# 14:37: error: invalid conversion from 'unsigned int' to 'node* first = new struct node* (sizeof(struct node));

Tags: c++

Below is the code please help I am new to c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} *first = NULL;

void Create(int A[], int n)
{
    int i;
    struct node *t, *last;
    first = new struct node *(sizeof(struct node));
    first->data = A[0];
    first->next = NULL;
    last = first;

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        t = new struct node *(sizeof(struct node));
        t->data = A[i];
        t->next = NULL;
        last->next = t;
        last = t;
    }
}

void Display(int *p)
{
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        cout << p.data;
        p = p.next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int A[] = {3, 5, 7, 9, 15}
    // struct node n1;
    Create(A, 5);
    Display(first);
    return 0;
}
```

The errors are

1. invalid conversion from 'unsigned int' to 'node*' [-fpermissive]
   first = new struct node* (sizeof(struct node));
2. 14:50: error: cannot convert 'node**' to 'node*' in assignment
   first = new struct node* (sizeof(struct node));

Comment: Simply use `first = new node;`.

Comment: "14:37" gives the line number and the column where the error occurred. The problem is `new struct node *(sizeof(struct node))`. What are you trying to do? (In C++ you don't have to keep saying `struct`, but that's not what's causing the problem.

Comment: What do you intend `first = new struct node *(sizeof(struct node))` to achieve?    Because the right hand side attempts to dynamically allocate a `node *` that is initialised with a `size_t` (which is an unsigned integral type).   And the compiler doesn't like that, because an integral value and a pointer are different things - there is no implicit conversion between them, and one cannot be used to initialise the other.   The result of that `new` expression has type `node **`, but `first` is a `node *` - and, again, there is no conversion from `node **` to `node *`.

Comment: This does not really look like C++. Have a look at smart pointers, `std::array` and `std::vector`

Answer (score 3):

First off, this looks like you're trying to convert C code to C++.

I'm assuming the original C code looks something like this:

```
first = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

C's malloc accepts a size in bytes. C++'s `new` will know the size of the node struct automatically:

```
first = new node();
```

To explain the error message: `new struct node *(sizeof(struct node))` is trying to allocate a pointer to node `node*` using an unsigned int `sizeof(struct node)`.

Also keep in mind that many things considered normal in C are weird in C++. Here are some suggestions:

- Use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`. NULL can easily turn into an integer 0 accidentally.
- You don't need `struct` when declaring variables, `struct node *t, *last;`  can be changed to `node *t, *last;`
- You can initialize the whole struct all at the same time, instead of setting the members afterwards: `first = new node{A[0], nullptr};`
- Arrays are NOT null-terminated, so the loop inside Display will glitch out. A better way to do this is to use std::array, std::vector, or just pass a count into the function. Also, this function tries to use ints as nodes? Assuming it isn't complete yet.
- Read about 'smart pointers' as it will lead to safer code that doesn't leak memory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `new` incorrectly. You are asking it to create a new `node*` pointer initialized with the return value of `sizeof`, which is wrong. You should instead be asking it to create a new `node` object.

Also, your `Create()` can be simplified. And your `Display()` is coded wrong. And you are leaking the list.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next = nullptr;
};

void Create(node* &first, int A[], int n)
{
    node **curr = &first;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        node *t = new node;
        t->data = A[i];
        *curr = t;
        curr = &(t->next);
    }
}

void Destroy(node *p)
{
    while (p)
    {
        node *n = p->next;
        delete p;
        p = n;
    }
}

void Display(node *p)
{
    while (p)
    {
        cout << p->data << ' ';
        p = p->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int A[] = {3, 5, 7, 9, 15}
    node *n1;
    Create(n1, A, 5);
    Display(n1);
    Destroy(n1);
    return 0;
}
```

That being said, you really should use `std::list` instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

void Display(list<int> &l)
{
    for (int val : l)
    {
        cout << val << ' ';
    }
}

int main()
{
    int A[] = {3, 5, 7, 9, 15};
    list<int> n1(begin(A), end(A));
    Display(n1);
    return 0;
}
```